# Will a former driveway support a swimming pool?

Tags: pool

Currently, we have a 28' travel trailer parked on a sloped concrete driveway in our backyard. We are selling our travel trailer soon and I was wondering if it is possible to convert that driveway into a swimming pool.

We have a corner lot that is sloped on the west side.  The house is at the top of the slope where the ground levels off.  The top of the driveway is somewhat level with our back patio and has a downward slope toward the street. The highest part of the yard/driveway is about 2-2.5' higher than the lowest part of the yard/driveway. At the bottom end of the yard/driveway, there is an 8' double gate where we pull out the trailer onto the street.

Is there a way to install a swimming pool on this driveway, where the deep end is on the bottom of the sloping end and the shallow end on the upper end of the slope where we can just walk into the pool and it gradually gets deeper as you walk toward the street?  I'm guessing retaining walls would have to be built around it.

Or would we have to bust up the concrete and dig out the higher end of the driveway so that it is level with the bottom end before installing? Is any of this affordably possible or would it be insanely expensive to do?  We are debating if we want to install a pool with a hot tub in place of the driveway or buy a boat and park it where the travel trailer is now.  I would prefer the pool.

Comment: Some pictures will help address the question. However, weight of the water may break up the driveway.

Comment: Currently there is no known above ground pool that can be built from a kit, that has one end deeper.  The weight is a problem.   I used to install above ground pools. The exterior ring or sides had to be placed exactly level to prevent a "bulge"  We used a transit to be sure it was level.    I have personal experience  with a pool and a boat.  My opinion is have a pool built.  More fun, less to clean, easier to maintain.  Cheaper in the long run.  never had someone steal my pool.

Comment: Yeah, the question is invalid as well as vague. No DIY pool can sit on a slope, and if you're having one built, ask the contractor.

Comment: For an above ground pool, find a model you are interested in and get the installation manual - that will tell you what ground conditions it wants.

Comment: I disagree with closing this question - it is answerable within the realm of DIY projects: read the manual.

Answer (score 3):

A hole with 18000 gallons of water or more is nothing to mess with.

A pool has to engineered to hold the massive weight of that much water.
It would be virtually impossible to get the permit for such an endeavor you are suggesting without the survey, plan, and engineering needed. getting all that and then the task of erecting the pool would be a greater cost than just hiring a pool company and have a pool built.

I think this plan should be nixed.